# Aligning the block of text with left and right margin

Tags: css

I have a block of text. I want to put a margin of 20% on the left side and margin of 30% on the right side. How can I acheive this using CSS?

Below is my code:

```css
.style4 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20%;
    background-color: #e5e0dd;
    width: 68.1%;
    margin-right: 30%;
    border-left:30%;

    text-align: center;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: small;
}

<div class="style4">
    This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.This is a test.
</div>
```

Comment: You already have `margin-left: 20%` and `margin-right: 30%`. What's not working with what you have?

Comment: This text is on top of a block this margin 20% and 30% is for that block. The block has 20% left marging and 30% right margin. The text on the block does not show that margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking to do padding rather than margin here.

```
padding-left: 20%; padding-right: 30%;
```